# UI Elements not affected by light

Tags: user-interface, button, unity-game-engine, text, light

I'm trying to make a menu screen in which all the UI elements (buttons, text...) are completely dark and by touching the screen you create a fire (or just an area light) that makes the UI elements visible.

Sort of like [this](http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/221260/header.jpg?t=1447356660)

I read that the default shader for the UI elements isn't affected by light, but i can't seem to change it.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score -1):

The UI elements by default use a unlit shader and are also rendered directly to clip space. so you'll need to do two things, first put a lit shader onto the elements, the unity standard shader should do fine, then you should change the canvas render mode to world space. with the canvas in world space you can move it around like it was a sprite. i would also recommend creating a second higher priority camera for the UI with culling turned off. with the canvas in view of the UI camera, you should be able to place a light source near it and see the resulting lighting on the UI.